# Controlling the order properties are filled by ASP.NET MVC IModelBinder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

In my custom ASP.NET MVC ModelBinder I have to bind an object of type MyType:

```
public class MyType
{
  public TypeEnum Type { get; set; }
  public string Tag { get; set; } // To be set when Type == TypeEnum.Type123
}
```

In the pseudo-code above you can see that I want the property 'Tag' to be set only when 'Type'  is Type123.

My custom ModelBinder lokks like that:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
  protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext cc, ModelBindingContext mbc, PropertyDescriptor pd)
  {
    var propInfo = bindingContext.Model.GetType().GetProperty(propertyDescriptor.Name);
    switch (propertyDescriptor.Name)
    {
      case "Type": // ....
        var type = (TypeEnum)controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["Type"].ToString();
        propInfo.SetValue(bindingContext.Model, name, null);
        break;
      case "Tag": // ...
        if (bindingContext.Model.Type == TypeEnum.Type123) { // Fill 'Tag' }
        break;
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that in my curstom ModelBinder I have no control on the order the properties are binded by ASP.NET MVC.

Do you know how can I specify the order the proerties are filled by ASP.NET MV?

Answer (score 1):

You could try overriding the `BindModel` method:

```
public class MyTypeModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = (MyType)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        if (model.Type != TypeEnum.Type123)
        {
            model.Tag = null;
        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

Comment: The point is, when BindProperty for Tag is invoked I want to be sure BindProperty for Type was already invoked so Type is set. This is the importat for me, even if the example doesn't illustrate this clearly ;-)

Comment: You cannot rely on any order. The properties will be bound in an arbitrary order. You will have to rethink your design if you have such requirement. In the example I have shown, I am calling the default model binder to set the 2 properties (which could happen in any order) and then undo its work if the type property is not Type123.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your custom model binder:

```
    protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor)
    {
        var formCollection = new FormCollection(controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form);
        base.BindProperty(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }
```

Then extract what you need from the formCollection. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the [`GetModelProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470147(v=vs.100).aspx) method and facilitate [`System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptorCollection.Sort(string[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy711ak6(v=vs.100).aspx) method to reorder the properties (note that this method has several overloads). In your case, this should get you the expected results:

```
protected override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetModelProperties(
    ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        return base.GetModelProperties(controllerContext, bindingContext)
            .Sort(new[] { "Type", "Tag" });
    }
```